# show inverse by matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Suppose $v^Tu \neq 1$ and $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Both $u$ and $v$ are column vectors. Define matrix $A=I+uv^T$. Show by matrix multiplication that $$A^{-1}=I-\frac{uv^T}{1-v^Tu}$$

My attempt: $$AA^{-1}=(I+uv^T)(I-\frac{uv^T}{1-v^Tu})=I-\frac{uv^T}{1-v^Tu} +uv^T-\frac{uv^Tuv^T}{1-v^Tu}=$$
$$I-\frac{1}{1-v^Tu}(uv^T-uv^T(1-v^Tu)-uv^Tuv^T)$$

I got stuck at part shown above. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you should have $\dfrac{uv^Tuv^T}{1-v^Tu}$ instead of $\dfrac{uv^T}{1-v^Tu}$

Comment: $v^Tu$ is a real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(I + uv^T)(I-\dfrac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}) &= I -\dfrac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu} +uv^T-\dfrac{uv^Tuv^T}{1+v^Tu} \\&= I-\dfrac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu} +uv^T-v^Tu\dfrac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu} \\ &=I +  uv^T -(1+v^Tu)\dfrac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}\\
& = I
\end{align}

So the right answer is $A^{-1} = I-\dfrac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}$

Comment: Can you explain second and third equalities?

Comment: @Idonknow $uv^Tuv^T = u(v^Tu)v^T$ and as you said in the comment $v^Tu$ is a real number, so  $u(v^Tu)v^T = (v^Tu)uv^T$